# LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabled=0 in the registry impacts to application authentication process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, openid, passport-azure-ad

I have a asp.net mvc4 application with .NETFramework 4.6, with AzureAD authentication and OpenID Connect protocol. Now with recent updates to Chrome80 SameSite=None update , application authentication is failing.

Here goes the Testing instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/miscellaneous/chrome-behavior-affects-applications#testing-guidelines

I used the below mentioned article which uses URLRewrite module to setup SameSite=None :

https://blog.elmah.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-secure-cookies-with-web-config-in-net/

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
   <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Remove Server Header">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="No SameSite">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None" negate="true" />
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

Update the flags in Chrome browser to Enabled:

[image]

Setting the value of LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabled in registry to 1 leads to successful application authentication but whereas if the LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabled is setup to 0 , then in case the application authentication is failing.

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing Chrome flags (`chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies`) with Chrome Enterprise Policy - [`​Legacy​Same​Site​Cookie​Behavior​Enabled`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabled).

The Chrome Enterprise Policies are intended for organisations that are maintaining legacy applications where the cookies are not easily updated. By setting that to `1` you are explicitly maintaining the old behaviour of cookies. If that's really what you want to do though, I would look at the more specific [`LegacySameSiteCookieBehaviorEnabledForDomainList` policy](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3/cookie-legacy-samesite-policies).

However, since you are attempting to update your app, I would ensure that you do not have either of the policies set, so that you can ensure the new behaviour is being enforced. You can visit https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me and if all the rows are green, then the new behaviour is enabled in your browser.

I'm not sure about your cookie rules, however I don't see you explicitly adding `Secure` to your `SameSite=None` cookies. Both of these must be set. I would also ensure that you are not simply adding `SameSite=None; Secure` to every singly cookie. Just do this for the ones you know need to be access from third-party contexts. For other cookies, consider `SameSite=Lax`.

If you need to see which cookies are being blocked on requests, you can check the network tab in Chrome DevTools. Specifically, select a request and check the cookies tab in there. You can find detailed instructions on https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug